# OData Model not refreshing

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm reading some OData on route matched.

This works fine fist time in, or when refreshed, but when I route to it from another view, the data has not update until I refresh the page again.

```js
_onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
    //initialise display
    var view = this.getView();
    view.setBusy(true);
    var oModel = this.getModel("outstanding");

    this.getModel().read("/CalendarSet", {
        filters: [
            new Filter("CategoryId", FilterOperator.EQ, "S"),
            new Filter("ApprovalId", FilterOperator.EQ, "0"),
            new Filter("EndDate", FilterOperator.EQ, "9999.12.31"),
            new Filter("DayOfWeek", FilterOperator.EQ, "0"),
            new Filter("SequenceNumber", FilterOperator.EQ, "00"),
        ],
        success: function (oData) {
            console.log(oData);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your view or control is not binded to model, it will not auto update the UI.
Bind model on view or control and refresh the model, when you are routing, to get updated data.This will update the bindings of corresponding controls.

```
_onRouteMatched: function(){ 
    oModel.refresh();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't include the full function, so it is bound. Looking deeper into this, it's the oData that isn't being refeshed after the read. Once I do the refresh though, the oData is fine.

Answer (score 0):

As your view or control is not binded to model, it will not auto update the UI. Bind model on view or control and refresh the model

oModel.refresh(true);